# I am trying to change the sign of a number to negative if it is below a specific target and it is to remain positive if it is above.

Tags: r, negative-number

I put the section of code in bold that seems to be the problem. Here is the code:

```
## price impact analysis

rm(list=ls())

### import data from excel spreadsheets
chtr_trades <- read.csv("F:/FRE 6951 Mkt Micro Struc/CHTRTRADES.csv")
chtr_quotes <- read.csv("F:/FRE 6951 Mkt Micro Struc/CHTRQUOTES.csv")

## initialize bid ask
max_bid <- NULL

min_ask <- NULL

### cleans data
maxrm <- function(x) {

  max(x, na.rm=TRUE)

}


minrm <- function(x) {

  min(x, na.rm=TRUE)

}


## retrieve max bid and ask for each iteration
max_bid<- tapply(chtr_quotes[,4],chtr_quotes[,3], maxrm)  
min_ask<- tapply(chtr_quotes[,5],chtr_quotes[,3], minrm) 
time <- levels(chtr_quotes[,3])

## calculate previous second midpoint 
midpoint <- (min_ask + max_bid)/2
askbidtime <- data.frame(midpoint,time,max_bid,min_ask)
row.names(askbidtime) <- seq(nrow(askbidtime)) 
askbidtime[,2] <- as.POSIXct(askbidtime[,2], format="%H:%M:%S")
ordered.askbidtime <- askbidtime[order(askbidtime$time),] 
row.names(ordered.askbidtime) <- seq(nrow(ordered.askbidtime)) 
chtr_trades_revised <-chtr_trades[which(as.POSIXct(chtr_trades[,3],format="%H:%M:%S") %in% ordered.askbidtime[,2]),]

midpoint<-NULL
midpoint[1:5] <- NA
for(i in 6:3917) {


  midpoint[i] <- as.numeric(ordered.askbidtime[which(ordered.askbidtime[,2]==as.POSIXct(chtr_trades_revised[i,3],format="%H:%M:%S"))-1,1])




}

***## sign trades
chtr_trades_revised$midpoint
chtr_trades_revised$midpoint <- midpoint
for(i in 6:3917) {
  if((!is.na(chtr_trades_revised$midpoint[i])) & (chtr_trades_revised$midpoint[i] > chtr_trades_revised$PRICE[i])) {
    chtr_trades_revised$signed_volume <- -chtr_trades_revised$SIZE
  }
  if((!is.na(chtr_trades_revised$midpoint[i])) & (chtr_trades_revised$midpoint[i] < chtr_trades_revised$PRICE[i])) {
    chtr_trades_revised$signed_volume <- chtr_trades_revised$SIZE
  }


}***
```

Here are the results. In the last column rows 4062 and 4054 should be positive but it makes the entire column negative:

```
     SYMBOL     DATE                TIME  PRICE SIZE midpoint signed_volume
4060   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 15:59:44 124.46  100  124.485          -100
4061   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 15:59:52 124.46  100  124.495          -100
4062   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 15:59:55 124.52  100  124.490          -100
4063   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 15:59:58 124.53  100  124.410          -100
4064   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 16:00:00 124.57 7951  124.550         -7951
4065   CHTR 20130718 2014-08-26 16:00:00 124.53  100  124.550          -100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cute way:

```
foo<- 1:10
threshold <- 5
foo<- foo*(-1)^(foo < threshold)
 foo
 [1] -1 -2 -3 -4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
foo = 1:10 ; threshold = 5
foo
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
foo = ifelse(foo>=threshold, foo, -foo)
foo
 [1] -1 -2 -3 -4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```